# Why are the different results when running debug and xUnit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, xunit

I am trying to unit test using xunit in C#.

the Results Wrong between debugging and xUnit. 
debug：return 1(my).
xunit: return 0(all).
My expected result is 1.(Method is 'getLevel')

I'm concern about one thing.
when I hover over "query" at runtime,
Debugging: "Auth.Datamodel.authDataModel" 
xunit: "null"
is displayed.

Please tell me about it.

This is auth.level

```
public enum level
{
 all,  // 0
 my    // 1
}
```

This is Linq Code.

```
public class EFauthRepository : IAuth
{
    private readonly authContext _context;

    public EFauthRepository(authContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public auth.level getLevel(string opeId)
    {
        var query = (from n in _context.AUTH
                    where n.ninId == "00001" &&
                          n.tanCd == opeId
                    select n).FirstOrDefault();

        if (query == null)
        {
            return auth.level.all;    // then xUnit
        }
        else
        {
            return auth.lebel.my;     // then debug
        }
    }
}
```

This is Test Code.

```
public class auth
{
    private authContext _authContext;

    public auth()
    {
        initContext();
    }

    public void initContext()
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<authContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("DATABASE_NAME");
        var context = new authContext(builder.Options);
        _authContext = context;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetLevelTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var EFauthRepository = new EFauthRepository(_authContext);

        // Act
        string opeId = "10000001";
        auth.level result = EFauthRepository.getLevel(opeId); //★Call the method

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your test where you're populating your in-memory database?

Comment: @scottdavidwalker
oh..thank you. 
I want to access the actual database, so don't I need inMemoryDatabase?

Comment: @scottdavidwalker
We succeeded!!! I delete useInMemoryDatabase, and then
useOracle(connectString) was added.

Comment: I would advise against what you're doing there. Using an actual database for a unit test is a big no no. If you need an actual database, use a dockerised container that you can create and destroy per test. Otherwise your unit tests will end up being a nightmare if they're reliant upon a database that every other test uses

Comment: @scottdavidwalker
oh..I see.
I need to think about when I run tests for data updates and when others run tests.
Consider unit tests using containers. Thanks.